# Keep program with list of functions from closing right away

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

How can I keep the program from closing right after initiation?

I want the user to use the functions listed and allow the user to close the window or kill the processes once they are finished.

```
import math

print("use start() to input equation and x() to input x's")

def start():
    #ask for intial variables

    global t
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global d
    global e
    global f
    global g


    t = int(input("highest degree coefficient: "))
    a = int(input("a: "))
    b = int(input("b: "))
    c = int(input("c: "))
    d = int(input("d: "))
    e = int(input("e: "))
    f = int(input("f: "))
    g = int(input("g: "))

def x():
    again = "yes"

    #runs if it is a quadratic

    if t == 2:

        #asks for x input

        x = float(input("x: "))

        #calculates

        ans = ((a) * x ** 2) + (b * x) + c

        #prints result

        print("f(x):",ans)

        #asks if there is more

        again = input("again?: ")
        again = again.lower()

        while again != "no":

            x = float(input("x: "))

            ans = ((a) * x ** 2) + (b * x) + c

            print("f(x):",ans)

            again = input("again?: ")
            again = again.lower()

    #runs if it is a cubic

    elif t == 3:
        #asks for x input

        x = float(input("x: "))

        #calculates

        ans = ((a) * x ** 3) + ((b) * x ** 2) + (c * x) + d

        #prints result

        print("f(x):",ans)

        #asks if there is more

        again = input("again?: ")
        again = again.lower()

        while again != "no":

            x = float(input("x: "))

            ans = ((a) * x ** 3) + ((b) * x ** 2) + (c * x) + d

            print("f(x):",ans)

            again = input("again?: ")
            again = again.lower()
    elif t == 4:
        #asks for x input

        x = float(input("x: "))

        #calculates

        ans = ((a) * x ** 4) + ((b) * x ** 3) + ((c) * x ** 2) + (d * x) + e

        #prints result

        print("f(x):",ans)

        #asks if there is more

        again = input("again?: ")
        again = again.lower()

        while again != "no":

            x = float(input("x: "))

            ans = ((a) * x ** 4) + ((b) * x ** 3) + ((c) * x ** 2) + (d * x) + e

            print("f(x):",ans)

            again = input("again?: ")
            again = again.lower()
    elif t == 5:
        #asks for x input

        x = float(input("x: "))

        #calculates

        ans = ((a) * x ** 5) + ((b) * x ** 4) + ((c) * x ** 3) + ((d) * x ** 2) + (e * x) + f

        #prints result

        print("f(x):",ans)

        #asks if there is more

        again = input("again?: ")
        again = again.lower()

        while again != "no":

            x = float(input("x: "))

            ans = ((a) * x ** 5) + ((b) * x ** 4) + ((c) * x ** 3) + ((d) * x ** 2) + (e * x) + f

            print("f(x):",ans)

            again = input("again?: ")
            again = again.lower()
    elif t == 6:
        #asks for x input

        x = float(input("x: "))

        #calculates

        ans = ((a) * x ** 6) + ((b) * x ** 5) + ((c) * x ** 4) + ((d) * x ** 3) + ((e) * x ** 2) + (f * x) + g

        #prints result

        print("f(x):",ans)

        #asks if there is more

        again = input("again?: ")
        again = again.lower()

        while again != "no":

            x = float(input("x: "))

            ans = ((a) * x ** 6) + ((b) * x ** 5) + ((c) * x ** 4) + ((d) * x ** 3) + ((e) * x ** 2) + (f * x) + g

            print("f(x):",ans)

            again = input("again?: ")
            again = again.lower()
    else:
        print("coming soon")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main program consists of an import and a print statement.  Then it defines two functions -- but never calls them -- and exits.

You need to call something useful from the main program, such as function **x**.  Better yet, move the user-inquiry logic from **x** to the main program.  Having the user type in "start()" won't do anything useful: that comes in as a character string, not a Python command.

Nothing in your code calls either function.  You need an outer (main program) structure something like this:

```
again = "yes"
while again != "no":
    start()
    x()
    again = input("again?: ")
    again = again.lower()
```

I strongly recommend that you start with the outer shell alone: make sure that you can repeat.  Next, add the quadratic case only; make sure that works before you add the higher-order ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following for loop to assign your variables in you `start` function:

```
def start():
    #ask for intial variables

    global t
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global d
    global e
    global f
    global g


    for letter in "tabcdefg":
        if letter == "t":
            var = input("highest degree coefficient: ")
        else:
            var = input(letter + ": ")

        if var == "quit":
            quit()

        else:
            globals()[letter] = int(var)
```

This way for each variable, if the user types `quit`, the programme will exit.

In your original code the `start`  and `x` functions are not called so you will need to put the following at the bottom of you code to ensure it executes:

```
while True:
    start()
    x()
```